# Verify the existence of an element in a table

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm new to C Algorithm and come to ask for some help.

I hope to check whether or not an element exists in a table, can anyone give me some good   algorithm? What I do is a cycle and a flag, then quit the cycle and verify the flag. But it looks like stupid, so I guess there would be more efficient algorithm. My code is following:

```
int j=0;
u8_t next_header[]={0x11, 0x22}; 
for(i = 0; i < sizeof(next_header); ++i)
{       
    if (buf[6] != next_header[i])
        continue;
    else
        ++j;            
}
if(j == 0)
{
// execution    
}
else
{
// execution
}
```

Comment: I believe you've confused the definition of "algorithm" with the definition of function. Algorithms are mathy-spuedocode-things that can process data structures. Functions in C are an implementation that runs on a computer. There is no such thing as a C Algorithm, just an algorithm implemented in C. The algorithm you've implemented is brute force search. You could speed it up with using linear search (break when you find the value). If your data has any other properties (such as it is sorted), we may be able to make it faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pack it in a function, so you can jump out of the loop using return as soon as the element is found:

```
int search_for_elements(int element)
{
    int i;
    u8_t next_header[]={0x11, 0x22}; 
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(next_header); ++i)
    {       
        if (element == next_header[i])
            return 1; // found the element;
    }
    return 0; // :( no element found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if your table is a simple array looping is the way to go. That said, the usual pattern is to use a break statement instead of a continue.

```
int found = 0;
for(i=0=; i<the_array_length; i++){
    if(array[i] == the_element_i_am_searching){
        found = 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

Also, its more idiamatic to test booleans with `if(i)` instead of `if(i != 0)`. (That said, if your variable is a number that is not always 0 or 1, like your `j` , I would keep the explicit comparison for clarity)